# Can't find password field to log into Google using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So, I'm coding a simple bot that just opens some apps and gives me my work for the day, and when I try to login to Google and I manage to find the username field and fill it, click the button to go to the next page but then, when I try to enter the password I just get a error saying that the password class or xpath(tried both) doesn't exist.
I have also tried waiting for the page to load, and still nothing.

There's the code. I might just be overlooking a simple thing:

```
emailLogin = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
emailLogin.send_keys(schoolUser)
browser.find_element_by_class_name("VfPpkd-RLmnJb").click()
passwordLogin = browser.find_element_by_class_name("whsOnd zHQkBf") passwordLogin.send_keys(schoolPassword)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_element_by_class_name`() accept only **single class name** not `multiple classes.`
You can use either `css selector` or `xpath` to use other attribute values to identify the element.

To avoid synchronisation issue use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`()

**XPath**:

```
 passwordLogin=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")))
 passwordLogin.send_keys(schoolPassword)
```

**Name**:

```
passwordLogin=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"password")))
```

**CSS selector:**

```
passwordLogin=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".whsOnd.zHQkBf[name='password']")))
```

You need to import below libaries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```